# Expresso Store Shipping not updating cost

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Expresso Store 2.2.0 and the only item in the CART that does not update is the 'Shipping' costs.

Instead of the price showing it reads '3' which is the number of the store Shipping Method in the STORE CP.

The code I'm using is:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="order_shipping">
<label>Shipping Country</label>
<br>
{field:shipping_country}
{if error:shipping_country}<p class="help-block">{error:shipping_country}</p>{/if}
</div>
<input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Shipping" class="btn" />
</div>
</div>
```

From this I get an output for a list of counties which is correct, but not a price!

The price should output put in this code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-9 cart-total">
<p class="text-right">Subtotal: <strong>&pound;{order_subtotal}</strong></p>
<p class="text-right">Discount: <strong>&pound;{order_discount}</strong></p>
<p class="text-right">Shipping to: {shipping_country_name} by {shipping_method}<strong>&pound;{order_shipping}</strong></p>
<p class="text-right">Total <strong>&pound;{order_total}</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
```

But it only putputs the number '3'.

I am using the same code on a live site with STORE 1.6 and it works fine!

Any ideas.

Comment: Hey Graham, are you using any shipping extensions or is this just with regular shipping rules and associated costs? Can you confirm what version of EE you have installed?

Comment: @ian Thank you for your reply. I'm using EE version of 2.7.2 I did notice that most of the min / max values for each country were at 0, so when I set these without any number value the cost the shipping worked! However the shipping method still outputs '3' when it should out put 'Royal Mail' which is what I set it up as.

Comment: Hmm, I think you want `{shipping_method_name}` - can you try that?

Comment: @IAN Yes, that worked. Many thanks for your help.